# Convergence value of series with exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

I was solving a problem and I came across the following expression,

$$\sum_n^N {N \choose n}\exp[-\beta n\omega]$$

I was looking for the convergence of this series but I couldn't find any resources which relates this sum of exponentials with a combinatory factor, so I was wondering if you have seen this series before or know any table where I can find general series for converging exponentials.

Comment: Let $x=\exp[-\beta\omega]$. You series is $\sum_{n}\binom{N}nx^n$. Does this look familiar?

Comment: Sum on $i$ or sum on $n$ ?

Comment: It seems to be a finite sum; how could convergence be a question?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Indeed, it remembers me to the binomial theorem with $\sum_n {N \choose n} x^n=(1+x)^n$, so substituting with $x=exp[-\beta \omega]$ I get $(1+exp[-\beta\omega])^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sum is of the form 
$$
\sum_n \binom{N}{n} a^n
$$
where $a = e^{-\beta\omega}$.
So by the binomial theorem, this is equal to
$$
\sum_n \binom{N}{n} a^n = (1+a)^n
$$
and the answer is
$$
(1+e^{-\beta\omega}
)^n
$$

Comment: Thank you, I did what they suggested above and I got the same result.